# Is it possible to adjust the boundary of `between` function in r?

Tags: r, data.table

In the document of `between` function,
there is an argument `incbounds` which can be used to adjust the boundary of both side.
However, it cannot adjust for only right hand or left hand side.

Is there anyway to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Which package is `between()` from? The `dplyr::between()` function has no `incbounds` argument.

Comment: @Patrick  data.table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an extra condition:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(43)
x <- sample(1:10)

> x[between(x, 2, 4, incbounds = TRUE)]
[1] 4 2 3
> x[between(x, 2, 4, incbounds = FALSE)]
[1] 3
> x[between(x, 2, 4, incbounds = FALSE) | x == 4]
[1] 4 3
```

In a function:

```
between_incupper <- function(x, l, u) between(x, l, u, incbounds = FALSE) | x == u
x[between_incupper(x, 2, 4)]
```

Comment: If you wanted to go _crazy_ ... `between2 <- function(x, lower, upper, incbounds = c(TRUE, TRUE)) { if (length(incbounds) < 2L) incbounds <- rep(incbounds, 2L); data.table::between(x, lower, upper, incbounds = FALSE) | (incbounds[1] & x == lower) | (incbounds[2] & x == upper); }`. (Part of me wonders if this will ever hit [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) on the `==` test when it would be okay in the native `data.table::between` ... a test for another day.)

Comment: Crazy and paranoid version: `x[between(x, 2, 4, incbounds = FALSE) | 
  between(x, 2 + .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5, 4, incbounds = TRUE)]`.